# Android: Unable to have two buttons at the bottom of a screen

Tags: android

I am trying to have a text view, a list view and two buttons at the bottom of the screen.
Here is my layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/widget36"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>
<TextView
android:id="@+id/textView"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="TextView"
android:gravity="center"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">
</TextView>
<ListView
android:id="@+id/listView"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
>
</ListView>
<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/darkgray"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
>
<Button
android:id="@+id/doneButton"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Button"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_weight="0.5">
</Button>
<Button
android:id="@+id/cancelButton"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Button"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_right="@+id/doneButton"
android:layout_weight="0.5">
</Button>
</RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Can you guys please help me out in figuring out what the issue is>

Comment: So what's the problem actually?

Comment: In my layout both the buttons are getting overlapped :(

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you want this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/widget36"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    >
    </TextView>
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
    >
    </ListView>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/darkgray"
    >
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/doneButton"
            android:text="Button"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
        >
        </Button>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/cancelButton"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
        >
        </Button>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Both the buttons @the bottom of the screen are not taking up the space available equally.

Comment: 0_0 really? I've tested this and they are equal. Except the case when 1 of them has too long text that fills more than 1 line. Or do you want them to take upper space?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to specifically place items you could try aligning them relative to the other items. So instead of:

```
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
```

You could use:

```
    <Button
    android:id="@+id/doneButton"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_weight="0.5">
    </Button>
    <Button
    android:id="@+id/cancelButton"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/doneButton"
    android:layout_weight="0.5">
    </Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have made changes in your code, check this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/widget36"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>
<TextView
android:id="@+id/textView"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="TextView"
android:gravity="center"
android:layout_above = "@+id/listView"
>
</TextView>
<ListView
android:id="@+id/listView"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_above="@+id/relativeLayout"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
>
</ListView>
<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#222222"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:gravity = "center_horizontal">
<Button
android:id="@+id/doneButton"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Button1"
android:layout_weight="0.5">
</Button>
<Button
android:id="@+id/cancelButton"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Button2"
android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/doneButton"
android:layout_weight="0.5">
</Button>
</RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set android:layout_width to wrap_content. Setting both buttons to fill_parent means that both buttons are going to be as wide as the screen.

Comment: I want both the buttons to take up the entire width of the screen equally.

Comment: Check this link: http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/msg/c66e677b79ec5f15